# Android: PKCS12 not found

Tags: android, kotlin, pkcs#12

In my Android application, I'm using PKCS12 certificates for https, authentication and it works.
But when I'm trying to display details from certificate in PKCS12 format, I'm getting exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLX509Certificate cannot be cast to javax.security.cert.X509Certificate
....     
java.security.cert.CertificateException: PKCS12 not found
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: PKCS12 CertificateFactory not available
```

This is the problematic code:

```
val p12 = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12")
val inputStream = ByteArrayInputStream(pkcs12Data)
p12.load(inputStream, password.toCharArray())
val e: Enumeration<*> = p12.aliases()
while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
    val alias = e.nextElement() as String
    try {
        val c = p12.getCertificate(alias) as X509Certificate
        val subject = c.subjectDN
```

Do I need to import something special to support PKCS12 ?

Comment: Your app seems to integrate conscrypt library which seem to cause problems. Check if you really need this library. Alternatively you could list all available providers and use the method version of `KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12")` that additionally allows to specify the provider to be used. That could allow you to select a different PKCS12 KeyStore implementation.